# Accessing jQuery custom object functions and properties

Tags: jquery, function, object, properties

Say I create an object as so:

```
$.myObject = function(parameter){
    var defaults = {
        start: '1'
    };

    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    function doSomething(){
        console.log('BOO');
    }
}
```

How can I access the function and access the properties from outside? They seem to be private (closure issue?).

Do I have to define the function outside to make them public?
i.e.

```
$.myObjectFunction = function doSomething(){
    console.log('BOO');
}
```

In order to call it from globally as $.myObjectFunction() from a console in firefox/chrome.

Comment: How can I access the function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) you can find a lot of examples how to work with classes in JavaScript

```
function myObject(options) {
    var defaults = {
        start: '1'
    };

    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    this.doSomething = function () {
        console.log('BOO');
        console.log(options.start);
    }
}
```

using:

```
new myObject().doSomething()
new myObject({start:'100'}).doSomething()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example.

```
(function ($) {
    $.myObject = function (options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.myObject.defaults, options),
        privateMethod = function (msg) {
            alert(opts.start + ': ' + msg);   
        };

        return {
            publicMethod: function (msg) {
                privateMethod(msg);
            }
        }
    };
    $.myObject.defaults = {
        start: '1'
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $.myObject().publicMethod('One');
    $.myObject({'start': '100'}).publicMethod('Two');
    $.myObject.defaults.start = '1000';
    $.myObject().publicMethod('Three');
    $.myObject().privateMethod('Four');
});
```